# Java file name from XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to save a file with the name from the xml publishing date.
My code its not working (everething else, does but not the part to get the date and save the file with the date as its name)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StringWriter filename = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename+".xml");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;


    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

        pw.println(inputLine);
        out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    pw.close();
    sw.close();
    out.close();

    String data = sw.toString();
    String test = filename.toString();

        Map<String,Double> currencies = new HashMap<String,Double>();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<Rate currency=\"([^\"]{3})\">(.+?)</Rate>");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
            Pattern date = Pattern.compile("<PublishingDate>(.+?)</PublishingDate>");
            Matcher datem = date.matcher(test);
            int pos = 0;
            while(matcher.find(pos)) {
              System.out.println("Found: " + matcher.group(1) + ": " + Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
              currencies.put(matcher.group(1), Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
              pos = matcher.end();
            }
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            boolean ok = true;
            while(ok) {
              System.out.println("What currency rate do you need? (QUIT to quit)");
              String cur = keyboard.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Rate for " + cur + " is " + currencies.get(cur));
              if("QUIT".equalsIgnoreCase(cur)) {
                ok = false;
              }else{
                  System.out.println("That`s not an option");
              }
            }    
            keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You use the `filename` variable before its even defined. Dont you think you should write to the file *after* you retrieve what the filename should be?

Comment: @ug_ I have tried adding it in the end of the file but with not success.I does not even print out the content now.

Comment: @ug_ I have done as you said but the filename is still just .xml , do you have any ideea why? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Better use XML parser than regex

First: you can use a filename to save the file, before you get this name.

Try this:

```
// First get Your URL INTO STRING (why not into File ...)
URL url=new URL ("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
if(urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection)
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
  // ELSE => STOP
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String urlString = "";
String current;
while((current = in.readLine()) != null)
   urlString += current+"\n";

// Now, You have your XML in urlString

// Do that because of xsi
xml="<root xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
xml+
"</root>";

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
//PARSE
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(urlString)));

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
//read a string value
String expression = "/root/DataSet/Header/PublishingDate";

NodeList nodes  = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

String the_date="";

for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
    Node the_node = nodes.item(i);

    if(the_node instanceof Element)
    {
     Element the_element=(Element) the_node;
     the_date=the_element.getTextContent();
     break;
    }
}

// WELL: YOU HAVE the_date, you can use it as a filename

File fileout=new File(the_date+".xml");
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileout));
out.write(xml);
out.close();
```